# Mongoose $and Filter doesn't Filter Properly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The `$and` operator in Mongoose isn't working properly in NodeJS.
Let's assume we have this JSON-MongoDB data:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("60bb4cd74a802722d8b0de0f"), 
    "username" : "System", 
    "text" : "matan has joined!", 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("60bb4cd74a802722d8b0de10"), 
    "username" : "System", 
    "text" : "Welcome!", 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("60bb4cdb4a802722d8b0de11"), 
    "username" : "matan", 
    "text" : "Hello World", 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("60bb4ce14a802722d8b0de12"), 
    "username" : "System", 
    "text" : "matan has left.", 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

I want to filter the data that all the `System's Welcome` messages will be dropped. For example, this output will be shown:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("60bb4cd74a802722d8b0de0f"), 
    "username" : "System", 
    "text" : "matan has joined!", 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("60bb4cdb4a802722d8b0de11"), 
    "username" : "matan", 
    "text" : "Hello World", 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("60bb4ce14a802722d8b0de12"), 
    "username" : "System", 
    "text" : "matan has left.", 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

But instead, only this output is shown:

```
{
    _id: 60bb4cdb4a802722d8b0de11,
    username: 'matan',
    text: 'Hello World',
    __v: 0
}
```

This is my code (NodeJS):

```
var msgs = Msg.find({
            $and: [
                { username: {$ne: "System"} },
                { text: {$ne: "Welcome!"} }
            ]
        }, (err, retn) => console.log(retn))
```

Did I miss something important? Thanks for the help.

Comment: *I want to filter the data that all the System's Welcome messages will be dropped* => why `$ne`?  use `$eq`.

Comment: I want all the data except for the system welcome.

Comment: just use `$or` instead of `$and`.

Comment: `$or` won't work because someone else can also send `Welcome!` message, or `System` can send message that is not `Welcome!`.

Comment: @NenadMilosavljevic he just wants to exclude system's welcome message, $or will not exclude others welcome message. see [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/c5ThBVSi6e4)

Comment: You are totally right! You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the $or operator instead

```
    var msgs = Msg.find({
        $or: [
            { username: {$ne: "System"} },
            { text: {$ne: "Welcome!"} }
        ]
    }, (err, retn) => console.log(retn))
```

Answer (score 3):

The `$and` condition with `$ne` will match that both fields should not equal to value.

You can just try `$or` condition,

```
var msgs = Msg.find({
  $or: [
    { username: { $ne: "System" } },
    { text: { $ne: " Welcome!" } }
  ]
}, (err, retn) => console.log(retn))
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/c5ThBVSi6e4)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Aggregation Pipeline:

- `$addFields` to add new field `flag` that will be `true` if both reqirements are met (`username` equals to `System`, and `text` equals to `Welcome!`), or `false` otherwise.
- `$match` to filter all documents where new field `flag` equals to false
- `$project` to remove the new field `flag` from final result

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "flag": {
        "$cond": {
          if: {
            "$and": [
              {
                "$eq": [
                  "$username",
                  "System"
                ]
              },
              {
                "$eq": [
                  "$text",
                  "Welcome!"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          then: true,
          else: false
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "flag": false
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "flag": 0
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the working example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/ENDzUW8igJP